A problem that is NP-complete on m by n grids
Is there any problem out there that is known to be NP-complete on the m by n grids?
I know domination is proved to be NP-complete even on the grids, but not on the m by n grids.
A grid graph in general, is a graph that its vertices are a subset of the integer coordinated points in the plane, and it is an induced subgraph of a m by n grid. Hence, m by n grids are a specific subfamily of the family of grid graphs.

what is "even on the grids" vs "m by n grids"? clarify your language

@kodlu A grid graph is a finite induced subgraph of the infinite grid according to Itai, Papadimitriou and Szwafcfiter. Zamfirescu and Zamfirescu call it a finite grid graph. Earlier Hedetniemi, Hedetniemi and Slater say that grid is a finite subgraph of a complete grid that is $P_n \times P_m$. However they consider induced subgraphs only.

The peculiarity of this question is that information quantity for $n \times m$ grid is $I = \log n + \log m$ only (for some constant base of logarithm). If the input contains essentially more information, like list of edges, then such input is redundant. See Garey and Johnson, Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness for details.
(The only possible exception is the recognition problem however it is a problem on arbitrary graphs.)
On the other hand any problem that supposes certificate for answer yes, that is at least linear on number of vertices or edges, has size that is exponential on $I$. Therefore any such problem doesn't belong to $\mathrm{NP}$ and can't be $\mathrm{NP}$-complete. It means that any problem that may be formulated for an arbitrary graph, or at least for an arbitrary grid graph, is unlikely to be $\mathrm{NP}$-complete for $n \times m$ grid.
Some $\mathrm{NP}$-complete problems from number theory like quadratic congruences potentially may be reformulated as problems on $n \times m$ grid graph, but for me it wouldn't look natural.

It's not clear from the question whether we allow weights on the vertices/edges.

@JohnKemeny then it would be a question about weighted grid graphs

Yes, precisely.

I am trying to understand what you are saying:
I am not sure what "unlikely" means in your response. If what you are saying is correct for m by n grids, then consider the graph burning problem for example:
specifically on a path-forest; that is, a forest with a finite number of path-components.  Its structure is even simpler than a m by n grid; however, it has been proved that the graph burning problem is NP-complete, even for path-forests.

@user24175 Unlikely means that I give a strong argument, but not a rigorous proof. Your comparison with forests is incomplete. It is true that forest on $nm$ vertices has less subgraphs than $n \times m$ grid graph. At the same time the number of unlabeled path-forests on $nm$ vertices equals to the partition number of $nm$ that is $e^{\Theta(\sqrt{nm})}$ according to Hardy and Ramanujan. While there are only $\mathrm O(\sqrt{nm})$ such grid graphs. It means that a grid graph brings exponentially less information than a forest on the same number of vertices.
